# Converting QImage an ZBar image

Tags: c++, qt, barcode, barcode-scanner, zbar

I am trying to convert an QImage into ZBar image but not able to do it successfully so far. My QImage is with RGB32 format(Attached)[image: QImage]

And I am instantiating ZBar as in the below snapshot code:

```
QImage qimg("/Users/apple/Pictures/image_0027.jpg");

zbar::Image image(qimg.width(), qimg.height(),
                  "Y800",
                  const_cast<uchar*>(qimg.bits()),
                  qimg.bytesPerLine());
zbar::ImageScanner scanner;
scanner.set_config(zbar::ZBAR_NONE, zbar::ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE, 0);
scanner.set_config(zbar::ZBAR_QRCODE, zbar::ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE, 1);
int n = scanner.scan(image);
qDebug() << "n = " << n;
```

I always see the value of n as 0. Not sure what else we can do. Can someone suggest? Thank you.

Tried converting the formats as well but since ZBar only accepts gray space we are limited there. Also tried changing `qimg.bytesPerLine()` to `qimg.widht()*qimg.height()`(as we do with cv::Mat) but to no avail.

Comment: When ImageScanner only accepts grayscale and you pass a color image what do you expect. You have to [convert](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimage.html#convertToFormat) the image to the desired format first.

Comment: @chehrlic I see your point. Doesn't the zbar image instantiation constructor take care of this? It passes 'Y800' as the third parameter.

I understand that you are asking me to convert RGB32 image to grayscale first and then pass it to zbar instantiation. 

My concern was to pass the data pointer. I would like to confirm that qimg.bits() is the right API for that? Thank you.

Comment: qimg.bits() points to the image data. And how should ybar do the conversion, esp. when it doesn't know the source format? The documentation explicitly states that you have to pass the data- in the format you specify.